# How do I make a keyboard shortcut open the windowed Calculator instead of the modern one?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, calculator

On my Asus laptop I can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> to open the calculator. However on Windows 8.1 it opens the modern Calculators which covers the entire screen. I prefer the old, windowed one which is still available (`calc.exe`), but I'd like to bind it to the original keyboard shortcut. How can I do it?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this question so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uninstall the modern Calculator.

1. Open the Start screen.
2. Type *"calculator"*, two calculators will appear: modern one (green icon) and windowed one (blue icon).
3. Right click the modern Calculator and select Uninstall.
4. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> and enjoy the classic Calculator.

If you ever decide you want the modern Calculator back, you can install it from the Store.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you make a shortcut on the desktop - a method that can be used for any program.

a) go to the apps page and find Accessories. Then right click on Calculator and click on 'Open file location'.

[image]

b) At the Calculator file location, right click on that and go to 'Send to' and then 'Desktop (create shortcut)'.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: By the way, it's easier to right click on desktop -> New -> Shortcut -> type `calc` -> Done.